# Algorithms behind load-balancers?

Tags: windows, linux, algorithm

I need to study about load-balancers, such as Network Load Balancing, Linux Virtual Server, HAProxy, etc. There're something under-the-hood I need to know:

- What algorithms/technologies are used in these load-balancers? Which is the most popular? most effective?

I expect that these algorithms/technologies will not be too complicated. Are there some resources written about them?

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but peradventure you are still working on this, you could be of help to me. I am currently implementing some load balancing policies and using them on the OpenStack cloud. Will you be willing to share ideas with me?

Answer (score 3):

Load balancing in Apache, for example, is taken care of by the module called mod_proxy_balancer. This module supports 3 load balancing algorithms:

- Request counting
- Weighted traffic counting
- Pending request counting

For more details, take a look here: [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this belongs on serverfault or not, but some load balancing techniques are:

- **Round Robin**
- **Least Connections**

I used least connections.  It just made the most sense to send the person to the machine which had the least amount of load.

Comment: I wanted to know about algorithms, that why I asked it here ^^

Comment: +1, least connections with a keep alive that is cached at a sensible TTL is also what I use. I've never seen round robin not end up with 'favorites' unless there's over 50 or so nodes involved.

Comment: @Vimvq1987 - true, but Systems Admins know more about the hardware than programmers due - at least typically.  If you want to know how these algorithms are written, then I have no idea ha

Comment: I have to study about software-based load-balancers, then I want to describe these algorithms in my thesis. I think programmers here will have well-knowledge about them :).

Answer (score 2):

In general, load balancing is all about sending new client requests to servers which are the least busy. Based on the application running, assign a 'busy factor' to each server: basically a number reflecting one/several points of interest for your load balancing algorithm (connected clients, cpu/mem usage, etc.) and then, at runtime, choose the server with the lowest such score. Basically ANY load balancing technique is based on something like this:

1. Round robin does not implement a 'busy score' per se, but assigns each consecutive request to the next server in a circular queue.
2. Least connections has its score = number_of_open_connections to the server. Obviously, a server with fewer connections is a better choice.
3. Random assignment is a special case - you make an uninformed decision about the server's load, but assume that the function has a statistically even distribution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to those already mentioned, a simple random assignment can be a *good enough* algorithm for load balancing, especially with a large number of servers.

Here's one link from Oracle:  http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/cluster/load_balancing.html

Comment: can you give me a link that this method is really used? :D.